# Xamarin.iOS project not running after xcode 11 update

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios

I got following error message:

**`SyscallError: setpriority(PRIO_DARWIN_ROLE, 412, 3): No such process`**

in the ios device log when trying to run my xamarin.ios project after updating to xcode 11.0 and the lastest Visual Studio for mac.

The reason why I updated xcode was because there was a xamarin.ios update that was incompatible with the xcode version I was using; **10.3**

My application starts, it shows the splash and then just stops running/crashes.

**Here's what I've tried:**

- Downgrading xcode, which didn't work because then it would mean I would have to downgrade my xamarin.ios version and of course my visual studio version, which is just not feasible.
- The most common one, clearing bin and obj folders and then rebuilding the project.
- Uninstalling and re-installing visual studio.

Has anyone experienced this issue and found a solution? All assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Create a new project and check if the issue still appears .

Comment: Okay I've done that and the issue doesn't  appear.

Comment: So  the crash may be caused by your code ,third-party library , project configuration , sdk version and so on (has nothing to do with IDE).

Comment: Crash only occurs on Xamarin.iOS though, works fine on my Xamarin.Android project

Comment: Did you do something more in iOS ? And what did your app do after finish launch (such as network request)?

Comment: It doesn't even get the opportunity to reach that point, just stops running after the splash screen is shown. No error messages in the error window, nothing. The only error message I was able to get was the one from the device log that I mentioned above.

Comment: What is the version of Xamarin.forms ? And Could you provide the full debug log ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I'm using Xamarin Version 4.2.0.848062.  Debug Log - https://pastebin.com/p8iDCaTY.  Device Log - https://pastebin.com/BY45q4D7.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200635/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-clifton-steenkamp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of investigation, trial-and-error and even updating my macOS to Catalina, I found the issue. Surprisingly it was something small and stupid(one line of code), would have honestly never thought of it. Anyway the issue was a line of code in my **`Main.cs`** that I somehow moved up to a commented line, perhaps I was clearing some line breaks.

**This is what my `Main.cs` looked like:**

```
public class Application
    {
        // This is the main entry point of the application.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate
            //you can specify it here. UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
    }
```

**This is obviously what it was supposed to look like:**

```
public class Application
    {
        // This is the main entry point of the application.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate
            //you can specify it here.
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
    }
```

The entry into my application had basically been commented out.

I apologise for wasting your time @LucasZhang-MSFT, regardless of that, I appreciate all your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

@CliftonSteenkamp I just stumbled across this while looking for something else; however, we recently had the exact same issue happen. I don't believe it was related to updating the SDK version; but the exact same line ended up in the comments of the line above. I can't see this happening to two people around the same time as being a coincidence. There may be more to what you're saying than a simple key press.

I should say the developer who this happened to did not update his version of Xamarin. I updated mine and to Xcode 11+; but he did not. So it could still be related.

Comment: Wow and there I was thinking it was just a stupid typo I had made, thanks for your input, I appreciate it.